# Add 'custom' function to javascript object

Tags: javascript, countdown

Sorry for the vague question, but wasn't sure how to phrase it.

I'm creating a timer (with a progress bar, that goes from 100% to 0), and I want to add something like a 'onStop' function for the user to use. This function would be called after the timer reaches 0. How would I add it to my class?

Current code:

```
"use strict";

const progressBar = { 

    // Default config, set to countdown starting at 3 minutes
    config: { 
        //  Define time in seconds 
        time: 180, // 3 minutes
        // Wrapper
        wrapper: '',
        // New element that will be the actual progress bar inside the wrapper
        bar: ''
    },

    //onStop: function() { console.log('triggered'); }, // custom function
    onStart: function() {}, // custom function

    bind: function(el) {
        this.createBar(el);
    },

    createBar: function(el) {
        const wrapper = document.getElementById(el);
        const bar = document.createElement("div");
        this.config.bar = bar;
        this.config.bar.id = "progressbar-inside";
        this.config.bar.style.width = '100%';
        this.config.bar.style.height = '100%';
        wrapper.appendChild(bar);
    },

    start: function() {
        //const percentage = 0.55
        const percentage = 100 / this.config.time;
        const time = this.config.time;
        progressBar.countDown(percentage, '100', time-1);
    },

    countDown: function(percentage, width, time) {
        const new_time = time-1;
        const new_width = width - percentage;
        this.config.bar.style.width = new_width + '%'

        console.log(time);  

        if (time === 0) {
            progressBar.onStop();
            return;
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            progressBar.countDown(percentage, new_width, new_time)
        }, 1000);
    }

}
```

Someone could use this like so:

```
progressBar.bind('progressbar');
progressBar.config.time = 25;
progressBar.start();
```

What should I add if I want to allow the end user to do:

```
progressBar.onStop(function() {
 // Timer finished! Do stuff here
});
```

Comment: You don't have a class in the first place. Your `progressBar` is an object.

Comment: Ok thanks, editing question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect the stop handlers inside of an array:

```
stopHandlers: [],
```

Then when `onStop` gets called just push the function to that array:

```
onStop(fn) { this.stopHandlers.push(fn); },
```

Then to trigger them (inside of some method):

```
   this.stopHandlers.forEach(fn => fn());
```